# I try to do this with canvas. Can do it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

## I try to draw a div inside a canvas with the following code

```
var DivCanvas=function(){
        this.div=document.createElement("div");
        this.posX=1;
        this.posY=1;
        this.width=1;
        this.height=1;
        this.dibujar=function(){
            bufferContexto.drawImage(this.div,this.posX,this.posY,this.width,this.height);
            contexto.drawImage(buffer,0,0);
        };
        this.getDiv=function(){
            return this.div;
        };
/*....*/
        this.setDiv=function(divAux){
            this.div=divAux;
        };
        /*....*/
    };
```

When I try to initialize it works.

```
divMensaje=new DivCanvas();
        divMensaje.setWidth(micanvas.width);
        divMensaje.setHeight(micanvas.height/4); //112
        divMensaje.setX(0);
        divMensaje.setY(micanvas.height-(micanvas.height/4)); //336
        divMensaje.getDiv().id="mensaje";
```

But when I try to draw does not work. My code stop when I try do it.

```
divMensaje.dibujar();
```

Comment: You cannot draw a `div` into canvas, only elements that are already visuals, like `img`, `video` and other `canvas`ses.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried a video and an image and it works. When div does not works, I would've imagined. Thank you!

Comment: I have added some more details in my answer. Also, just for the future, there is no harm in leaving some space around `=` signs, would make your code much easier to read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation at MDN:

### `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`

```
void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy);
```

> **image**
> An element to draw into the context. The specification permits any canvas image source (CanvasImageSource), such as an HTMLImageElement, an HTMLVideoElement, an HTMLCanvasElement or an ImageBitmap.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Focus on this:

> HTMLImageElement, an HTMLVideoElement, an HTMLCanvasElement or an ImageBitmap

Which are all variaties of CanvasImageSource - which a `div` is not. (MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasImageSource)